# how to build android app cordova

Tags: java, android, ant, cordova

i've been trying to build a cordova / android app this afternoon but i did not succeed ...

I created my project by the usual way : 'cordova create [NAME]'

i followed all the steps i could have found and even more, documentation, some post on SO ..
So, i did install cordova using node Js, i installed java JDK and set the JAVE_HOME, same with ant, i did install the adnroid SDK and set it into the PATH, installed the build tool .. when i'm trying to do this command : 'cordova platform add android -d', it gives me a huge error which is :

> Requesting {"uri":"https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git
>   ;a=snapshot;h=3.1.0;sf=tgz"}...
>   Downloaded, unzipped and extracted 506952 byte response.
>   Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
>   Checking Android requirements...
>   Running "android list target" (output to follow)
>   Available Android targets:

```
id: 1 or "android-14"
 Name: Android 4.0
 Type: Platform
 API level: 14
 Revision: 3
 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
XGA720, WXGA800
 ABIs : armeabi-v7a

id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:14"
 Name: Google APIs
 Type: Add-On
 Vendor: Google Inc.
 Revision: 2
 Description: Android + Google APIs
 Based on Android 4.0 (API level 14)
 Libraries:
  * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
      API for USB Accessories
  * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
      API for Google Maps
 Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default)
, QVGA, WXGA800
 ABIs : armeabi-v7a

id: 3 or "android-17"
 Name: Android 4.2.2
 Type: Platform
 API level: 17
 Revision: 2
 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
 XGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 ABIs : armeabi-v7a, mips, x86

 id: 4 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
 Name: Google APIs
 Type: Add-On
 Vendor: Google Inc.
 Revision: 3
 Description: Android + Google APIs
 Based on Android 4.2.2 (API level 17)
 Libraries:
  * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
      Collection of video effects
  * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
      API for USB Accessories
  * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
      API for Google Maps
 Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA
 800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
 ABIs : armeabi-v7a

 Running "android update project -p "C:\Users\T234106\.cordova\lib\android\cordov
 a\3.1.0\framework" -t android-17" (output to follow)...
 Updated project.properties
 Updated local.properties
 build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
 Added file C:\Users\T234106\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\framework\proguar
 d     -project.txt

 Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\T234106\.cord
 ova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\T234106\RippleSites\MR\plat
 forms\android" "io.cordova.hellocordova" "MondialRelay"" (output to follow)
 Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
 Command failed to execute : ant jar

 Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova
  project for the Android platform:
 Command failed to execute : ant jar
```

I also tried to remove the .cordova folder that is into my User folder ..

If someone could just take few minutes to help me out .. ;)
thank you !

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Did you check the ANT folder, Android SDK Platform and SDK tools are referenced in the system environment variable. If you remove the .cordova use the node js command prompt to install. Refer this blog which was helpful to me http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2014/04/creating-phonegap-project-with-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it a permissions issue on execution of the ant jar?

Answer (score 0):

which version of ant you have. Cordova 3.3 demands 1.8.0.  Also, Please check again your path, is it pointing correctly to this new version of Ant? If any duplication/reference to lower version of ant to some where else remove it from path.